# Fetching records that do not exist based on condition in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following data.

| CTN | PROD | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | prod1 | null |
| 1234 | prod2 | null |
| 1234 | prod3 | null |
| 234 | prod1 | null |
| 345 | prod2 | null |

CTN can have prod1. When CTN has Prod1 , prod2 or prod3 can accomany it. i need to identify CTN s where only prod1 exists

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, and _specify_ the expected result. And show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

How about this option?

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test order by ctn, prod;

       CTN PROD       A_DATE
---------- ---------- ----------
       234 prod1
       345 prod2
      1234 prod1
      1234 prod2
      1234 prod3
```

Query, which expects `CNT`s whose MIN and MAX `PROD` column values are the same (which means that there's only one `PROD` per that `CTN`), and - at the same time - `PROD`s value is equal to `prod1` (i.e. the one you're looking for):

```
SQL> select ctn
  2  from test
  3  group by ctn
  4  having min(prod) = max(prod)
  5     and min(prod) = 'prod1';

       CTN
----------
       234

SQL>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try it:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM DWH.Data A
JOIN
    (SELECT CTN,
            COUNT(*)
        FROM DWH.Data
        GROUP BY CTN
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) B ON A.CTN = B.CTN
WHERE PRO = 'prod1';
```